# Will the operation of collect from Flow cost many system resources when I use Compose with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The `SoundViewModel` is a `ViewModel` class, and `val listSoundRecordState` may be used by some modules in the App.

In Code A, I invoke `fun collectListSoundRecord()` when I need to use the data `listSoundRecordState`. But `fun collectListSoundRecord()` may be launched again and again because of Jetpack Compose recomposition, I don't know if it will cost many system resources?

In Code B, I launch  `private fun collectListSoundRecord()` in `init {  }`, `collectListSoundRecord()` will be launched only one time, but it will persist in memory until the App code closed even if I needn't to use the data `listSoundRecordState`, will the way cost many system resources?

**Code A**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
  ...
): ViewModel() {

    private val _listSoundRecordState = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<MRecord>>>(Result.Loading)
    val listSoundRecordState = _listSoundRecordState.asStateFlow()

    init { }

     //It may be launched again and again
    fun collectListSoundRecord(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            listRecord().collect {
                result -> _listSoundRecordState.value =result
            }
        }
    }

    private fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
        return  aSoundMeter.listRecord()
    }

}
```

**Code B**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
  ...
): ViewModel() {

    private val _listSoundRecordState = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<MRecord>>>(Result.Loading)
    val listSoundRecordState = _listSoundRecordState.asStateFlow()

    init { collectListSoundRecord() }

    private fun collectListSoundRecord(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            listRecord().collect {
                result -> _listSoundRecordState.value =result
            }
        }
    }

    private fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
        return  aSoundMeter.listRecord()
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also us `collectAsState` on listRecord flow to use it directly in Composable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably benefit from collecting the original flow (from `listRecord()`) only when there is a subscriber to your intermediate flow (the one you keep in your `SoundViewModel`) and cache the results.

A subscriber, in your case, would be a `Composable` function that collects the values (and may recompose often).

You can achieve this using the non-suspending variant of [`stateIn()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html), since you have a default value.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class SoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    ...
): ViewModel() {

    val listSoundRecordState = listRecord().stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), Result.Loading)

    private fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
        return  aSoundMeter.listRecord()
    }
}
```

In order to use the `StateFlow` from the UI layer (a `@Composable` function), you will have to transform it into a `State`, like so:

```kt
val viewModel: SoundViewModel = viewModel()
val listSoundRecord = viewModel.listSoundRecordState.collectAsState()
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean it doesn't cost many system  resource if I don't  subscribe a Flow even if I have launched a Collect operation in a viewmodel?

Comment: And by your way, I should launch `private fun collectListSoundRecord()` in `init {  }` of the viewmodel, right?

Comment: You do not need `collectListSoundRecord()` anymore, because when you call `collect {}` on `listSoundRecordState` in the UI layer, the flow will start the collection automatically, using the provided scope, in this case `viewModelScope`. And to answer your first question, the solution I proposed is the most efficient way you can achieve this, so no need to worry anymore about system resources. When the Composable function decides to recompose, it will reuse the previous source, not restart any work.

Comment: Thanks!  Vygintas  told me `I can also use collectAsState on listRecord`. I have tested, it's OK.  Could you tell me which is better betweem your way and his way?

Comment: If you only use `collectAsState()` (and preferably with `remember`, like this: `remember { viewModel.listRecord() }.collectAsState(Result.Loading)`), the main differences are: 1. If two composable functions use the same flow, it will be collected twice, so the data will not be shared, and this is undesirable if your flow makes, for example, network calls directly. 2. You need to specify the default value every time. It might be better to decouple this logic and store it, like I suggested, in the ViewModel. I have updated my answer to show you how to use my suggested code from the UI layer

Comment: Thanks! `collectAsState`  is wrapped with `remember`, so I needn't to use `remember { viewModel.listRecord() }.collectAsState(Result.Loading))`,  right?

Comment: The two options are `remember { viewModel.listRecord() }.collectAsState(Result.Loading)` (using `listRecord()` directly, `remember` is needed here in order to use the same flow instance every time the function recomposes) and `viewModel.listSoundRecordState.collectAsState()` (using my approach, with `stateIn`, which shares the results among collectors)

Answer (score 0):

I use the below implementation of `composable` with `view-model` using `LaunchedEffect`

**PokemonDetailScreen.kt**

```
@Composable
fun PokemonDetailScreen(
    dominantColor: Color,
    pokemonName: String,
    navController: NavController,
    topPadding: Dp = 20.dp,
    pokemonImageSize: Dp = 200.dp,
    viewModel: PokemonDetailVm = hiltViewModel()
) {

    var pokemonDetailData by remember { mutableStateOf<PokemonDetailView>(PokemonDetailView.DisplayLoadingView) }
    val pokemonDetailScope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
        viewModel.getPokemonDetails(pokemonName)
        viewModel.state.collect{ pokemonDetailData = it }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(dominantColor)
            .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
    ) {

        PokemonHeader(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
        ) {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }

        PokemonBody(
            pokemonInfo = pokemonDetailData,
            topPadding = topPadding,
            pokemonImageSize = pokemonImageSize
        ) {
            pokemonDetailScope.launch {
                viewModel.getPokemonDetails(pokemonName)
            }
        }

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {


            if(pokemonDetailData is PokemonDetailView.DisplayPokemonView){

                val data = (pokemonDetailData as PokemonDetailView.DisplayPokemonView).data

                data.sprites.let {
                    // Image is available
                    val url = PokemonUtils.formatPokemonDetailUrl(it.frontDefault)
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                            .data(url)
                            .crossfade(true)
                            .build(),
                        contentDescription = data.name,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            // Set the default size passed to the composable
                            .size(pokemonImageSize)
                            // Shift the image down from the top
                            .offset(y = topPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**PokemonDetailVm.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class PokemonDetailVm @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PokemonRepositoryFeature
): ViewModel(){

    private val _state = MutableSharedFlow<PokemonDetailView>()
    val state = _state.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun getPokemonDetails(pokemonName:String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when(val pokemonInfo = repository.getPokemonInfo(pokemonName)){
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    pokemonInfo.message?.let {
                        _state.emit(PokemonDetailView.DisplayErrorView(message = it))
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.emit(PokemonDetailView.DisplayLoadingView)
                }
                is Resource.Success ->  {
                    pokemonInfo.data?.let {
                        _state.emit(PokemonDetailView.DisplayPokemonView(data = it))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```